Gradle 8.x upgrade : How to fix "JUnitXmlReport.getDestination()" error in build
I have upgraded a repo from Gradle 7.5 to Java 8.5 (running on Java 17 for now)
After the upgrade, the repo still builds fine locally, but started to fail in the deployed build (AWS CodeBuild) with the followiing error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: 'java.io.File org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.JUnitXmlReport.getDestination()'


I understand that the 'destination' property has changed to 'outputLocation' in Gradle 8.x, however I did not currently have any direct references to 'destination' in my existing config, that could be changed to 'outputLocation'.  Nor did I have any direct references to the JUnitXmlReport in my existing config.  The relevant section of the existing gradle.build file is simply:
jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.8'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        html.required = true
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform() {
        includeEngines 'junit-vintage'
        includeEngines 'spock'
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

test.dependsOn copyNativeDeps
test.doFirst {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", 'build/libs'
}

Any help with the appropriate configuration to fix this problem greatly appreciated

If you run the task with the -s flag it will print a stacktrace which should show you the class/plugin which is calling the outdated method

I'd try and explicitly update and assign a path:
jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.8'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml {
            required = true
            outputLocation = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml") // Set output location explicitly
        }
        html {
            required = true
            destination = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/test/html") // For HTML report
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform() {
        includeEngines 'junit-vintage'
        includeEngines 'spock'
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

test.dependsOn copyNativeDeps
test.doFirst {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", 'build/libs'
}

